# dpkg-shlibdeps fails with “no dependency information found”

Tags: package-management, dpkg, cuda

I am building a custom debian package for tensorflow. At some point, when I run

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

I get:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1 (used by debian/libhal-tensorflow-cc/usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so)
Hint: check if the library actually comes from a package.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/libhal-tensorflow-cc.substvars debian/libhal-tensorflow-cc/usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so debian/libhal-tensorflow-cc/usr/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so returned exit code 2
debian/rules:9: recipe for target 'binary' failed
```

I looked up this page: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg-dev/dpkg-shlibdeps.1.en.html
and tried to follow the steps performed by this tool to get the dependency information:

```
$ dpkg -S libcurand.so.9.1
cuda-curand-9-1: /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1
cuda-curand-9-1: /usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1.85
```

Actually, there is a corresponding .shlibs file for this package:

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/cuda-curand-9-1.shlibs
libcurand 9.1 cuda-curand-9-1
```

I checked if the package is actually installed, and it is:

```
$ apt list | grep cuda-curand-9-1

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cuda-curand-9-1/unknown,now 9.1.85-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

so I am out of ideas what it complains about

Comment: The first thing I notice is that `cuda-curand-9-1` is installing a library to `/usr/local`.  That path is reserved for non-packaged software so I would first suspect `cuda-curand-9-1`

Comment: The second thing I notice is `dpkg-shlibdeps` is looking at `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1`, while your `dpkg` is looking at `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1`.  They are not the same path or package.

Comment: Right, it skipped my attention that these two locations are different.

Answer (score 3):

`dpkg-shlibdeps` is looking for information about `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcurand.so.9.1`, but the `cuda-curand-9-1` package ships `/usr/local/cuda-9.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcurand.so.9.1`, which isn’t the same.

You need to ensure that `libtensorflow_framework.so` ends up linking against the shipped library, with the right path. Alternatively, you can provide the dependency information in `debian/shlibs.local` in your own package, or override `dpkg-shlibdeps` entirely.

Ideally, `cuda-curand-9-1` should be fixed to ship its libraries in the canonical locations for a Debian system (`/usr/lib/<triplet>`).